# Parse a .txt file and display it in textbox in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

**My Program:** Contains 5 textboxes as shown below in the image:

[image]

**My Goal:** I want to parse the settings.txt file for anything after colon **" : "**. So, for example: I want **(459800090581).** to be displayed in my first textbox after reading the 'First Manual: (459800090581).' line from Settings.txt file. This is applies to other individual respective fields.

I tried to Google on how to parse a text file but I was unable to find a simple file parsing program which will help me learn and understand how to do file parsing in C#. This program will help me learn this technique quickly and easily, and your help will be much appreciated! Thanks!! :)

Comment: Look into [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) which will return an array containing each line. Then look into the [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method to split on the colon. This will get you the string you want at which point you can add them to your Textboxes.

Comment: The first thing you need to do in a scenario like this is break the problem up into smaller parts. The first is clearly how do you read a file line by line. Once you can do that then you need to parse each line. I am amazed you couldn't find any resources on either of these.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should do the job;

```
var path = @"---"; //Path to your settings file.
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
        System.IO.StreamReader sis = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
        rtb.Text = sis.ReadToEnd();
        sis.Close();
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (string line in rtb.Lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains("(") == true && line.Contains(")") == true)
            {
                counter++;
                string numbers = line.Substring(line.IndexOf("("), line.IndexOf(")") - (line.IndexOf("(") - 1));
                switch (counter)
                {
                    case 1:
                        textBox1.Text = numbers;
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        textBox2.Text = numbers;
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        textBox3.Text = numbers;
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        textBox4.Text = numbers;
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        textBox5.Text = numbers;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: There's no need to create a RichTextBox just to get each line in a string. You're also emulating the String.Split functionality unnecessarily.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Aviral Singh. It works. :) Thanks again for helping me.

Answer (score 6):

Start with something like the following:

```
char[] delimiters = new [] { ':' };

foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(@"some path"))
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
    {
        string[] parts = line.Split(delimiters);

        if (parts != null && parts.Length == 2)
        {
            string label = parts[0];
            string value = parts[1];

            Console.WriteLine("Label: {0}, Value: {1}", label, value);
        }
    }
}
```

See [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx), [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx), and [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx).